# Custom domain for Node.js apps

Tags: node.js

Are there any PaaS services available for Node.js where you can add a custom domain to your Node app?

For exampe, nodejitsu, nodester, ...

Comment: I think, **ANY** PaaS service.

Answer (score 3):

Heroku does, not sure about nodejitsu or nodester...

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains

Comment: Thanks, i already checked and they both support custom domains. Nodejitsu: http://dns.nodejitsu.com/, nodester: http://blog.nodester.com/post/3254776172/custom-domains-now-supported-on-nodester

Answer (score 0):

nodejitsu support customized domain. See https://www.nodejitsu.com/documentation/features/dns/

Here are more easier steps to set a custom domain on nodejitsu

- Set the CNAME record point to jit.su
- Add `domains` property into package.json

  ```
  "domains": [
      "myawesomedomain.com",
      "www.myawesomedomain.com"
  ],
  ```